# How to add custom css to github page

Tags: html, css, youtube

I am trying to use an embed YouTube video for my GitHub webpage. I followed the suggestion given by **`@Darwin`** in **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737557/how-can-i-make-the-youtube-player-scale-to-the-width-of-the-page-but-also-keep-t)**. However, I don't know where should I add CSS commands. I am new to GitHub pages.

Answer (score 0):

Your repository should contain a `CSS` file and it should be linked to the `HTML` page.

> **Check this out: https://pages.github.com/**

Comment: Can you give an example? I already have a running website that is fully functional.